# Accessing ArcGIS JS API outside of require callback

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am trying to figure out how I can access the ArCGIS JS API from a map after the map has been rendered, outside of require (ArcGIS JS API uses Dojo). For example, so I can do stuff like add (or remove) points, and perform other operations on the map.

I can create a map as follows:

```
require(["esri/config", "esri/Map", "esri/views/MapView", "esri/Graphic",
      "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer"
    ], function(esriConfig, Map, MapView, Graphic, GraphicsLayer) {
      esriConfig.apiKey = "";
      const map = new Map({
        basemap: "arcgis-topographic"
      });
      const view = new MapView({
        map: map,
        center: [-81, 41],
        zoom: 9,
        container: "viewDiv"
      });
});
```

And I can add a point using this function:

```
function plotPoint(lat, long, props) {
    const popupTemplate = {
        title: "{Name}",
        content: "{Description}"
    }
    
    const attributes = {
        Name: props.name,
        Description: props.desc
    }
    
    const graphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();
    map.add(graphicsLayer);
    
    const point = {
        type: "point",
        longitude: long,
        latitude: lat
    };
  
    const simpleMarkerSymbol = {
        type: "simple-marker",
        color: [226, 119, 40],
        outline: {
          color: [255, 255, 255],
          width: 1
        }
    };
    
    const pointGraphic = new Graphic({
        geometry: point,
        symbol: simpleMarkerSymbol,
        attributes: attributes,
        popupTemplate: popupTemplate
    });
  
    graphicsLayer.add(pointGraphic);
}
```

But `plotPoint` needs to be within the require callback so it can access the referenced modules. I could assign it to the global `window` object so I could call it outside of require, but then I may run into an issue where the function is called before it's defined.

I may need to perform other operations too from other points in the code, like removing points, adding feature layers, etc. Unfortunately, this must all exist inside some legacy code, so I can't refactor the entire application.

Is there a better pattern for accessing the API outside of require?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to pass the module variables into the function:

```js
function plotPoint(lat, long, props, Graphic, GraphicsLayer) {
  // ... you can use "Graphic" and "GraphicsLayer" here!
}

require(["esri/config", "esri/Map", "esri/views/MapView", "esri/Graphic",
      "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer"
    ], function(esriConfig, Map, MapView, Graphic, GraphicsLayer) {
      esriConfig.apiKey = "";
      const map = new Map({
        basemap: "arcgis-topographic"
      });
      const view = new MapView({
        map: map,
        center: [-81, 41],
        zoom: 9,
        container: "viewDiv"
      });
      plotPoint(lat, long, props, Graphic, GraphicsLayer);
});
```

Another option is to use the new ES Modules version of the ArcGIS API for JavaScript: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/es-modules/

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Perhaps not ideal, but it works. The module approach would be better in the long run, but passing references to the modules in the function call will do the trick for now.